# how to prepare image data for using in torch

Tags: torch

I want to prepare my own image data for training in torch.

I tried to find a good source for this but could not find.
They have given reference to data that has been already prepared in .lua or .t7 formats.

Can you please explain the procedure of preparing raw image data for torch? (training, validation and test sets)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you may try to write your own data loader class. store your image paths in a table, read image using

```
require 'image'
YOUR_RGB_FILE_PATH = "/home/username/image.png"
img = image.load(YOUR_RGB_FILE_PATH, 3)
```

Write your lua code in a [iTorch notebook](https://github.com/facebookarchive/iTorch), it helps you debug quickly.

if you do not know how to start, you can refer to the [project here](https://github.com/fucusy/Cross-View-Gait-Based-Human-Identification-with-Deep-CNNs/blob/master/prepareDataset.lua) wrote with lua torch.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'io'
require 'torch'
require 'image'

------------------------------ Parameters ---------------------------------
file_name = '.../train.txt'
save_name = '.../train.t7'

num_images = 10000*3
num_channels = 3
width = 51
height = 51
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

file = io.open(file_name, 'rb')
data = torch.Tensor(num_images, num_channels, width, height):byte()
label = torch.Tensor(num_images):byte()
counter = 1

for line in file:lines() do
    print(counter)
    image_name, image_label = line:split(' ')[1], line:split(' ')[2]
    data[counter] = image.load(image_name, num_channels, 'byte')
    label[counter] = image_label
    counter = counter + 1
end

torch.save(save_name, {data = data, label = label})
```